# Response card are not showing up when i integrate the AWS lex with a website

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have created a AWS lex chat bot and successfully integrated it on dummy website.
I am having a problem in response card part.

The buttons which I created through the user interface or through lex are showing up in website and working fine.

But the buttons that I created through lambda function are working fine in the test platform of AWS lex but when I test it on a website then it just disappears hence buttons created through the lambda function are not showing up.

How to resolve this problem?